# Android Recycler Pagination : Room + RxJava + MVP

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room

I'm new to `RxJava`, I've been reading so many articles about this subject and I've well understood the concepts of reactive programming in general and `RxJava` operators for room specifically.

Most of the apps I build rely on `MVP` architecture, Where the presenter is responsible of binding the `ViewHolders`, In this case, the `RecyclerViewAdapter` knows only about items count, and then it asks the presenter to bind each item based on it's list position. Here's a binding code example :

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (holder is MvpRecyclerContract.MvpUnbindableHolder) {
        holder.bindListener(listener)
    }
    else (holder as? HOLDER)?.apply {
        this.listPosition = position - headersCount
        bindListener(listener)
        presenter.bindRecyclerHolder(this)
    }
}
```

And here's what does the `RecyclerViewAdapter` know about:

```
override fun addMoreData(newDataCount: Int) {
    listItemCount += newDataCount
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Each ViewHolder gets binded by the presenter through a similar Interface :

```
interface MvpOrderHolder : MvpHolder {
    var orderId: Int?
    fun setDate(date: String)
    fun setTotalPrice(price: String)
    fun setTotalOldPrice(oldPrice: String)
    fun setTotalDiscount(discount: String)
}
```

The ViewHolder knows nothing about the model, it only displays what the presenter wants to

```
class MvpOrderHolder(itemView: View) : MvpRecyclerHolder(itemView), MvpRecyclerContract.MvpOrderHolder {

override var orderId: Int? = 0
    set(value) {
        field = value
        itemView.orderId.text = value.toString()
    }

override fun bindListener(listener: MvpRecyclerContract.MvpHolderListener) {
    itemView.apply {
        setOnClickListener {
            listener.onHolderClick(listPosition, adapterPosition, this@MvpOrderHolder.orderId)
        }

        setOnLongClickListener {
            listener.onHolderClick(listPosition, adapterPosition, this@MvpOrderHolder.orderId)
            true
        }
    }
}

override fun setDate(date: String) {
    itemView.date.text = date
}


override fun setTotalPrice(price: String) {
    itemView.totalPrice.text = price
}

override fun setTotalOldPrice(oldPrice: String) {
    with(itemView.totalOldPrice) {
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
        paintFlags = paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        text = oldPrice
    }
}

override fun setTotalDiscount(discount: String) {
    with(itemView.totalDiscount) {
        visibility = View.VISIBLE
        hint = discount
    }
}


}
```

On scroll, the adapter requests more data, it sends a request to the `Presenter` and then the `Presetner` communicates with the `Repository`.

```
override fun loadMoreData() {
    presenter.loadMoreRecyclerData(this)
}
```

My apps used to request an `ArrayList` of `Object` from Room using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` which are controlled by the repository using `paginationSize` and `currentItemCount`, and store it in the `Presenter`. Each returned list is actually the next list, the `Presenter` will add it to the previously loaded list and notify the adapter of data change this way :

```
repository.apply {

    onListSuccess = {
        networkError = false
        data.addAll(it)
        allData = it.size < paginationSize
        addMoreData(it.size)
        isLoading = false
        setViewRefreshing(false)
    }

    onFailure = {
        networkError = true
        addMoreData(0)
        isLoading = false
        setViewRefreshing(false)
    }

    getNextPage()
}
```

And here's how's the `Repository` handling it :

```
override fun getNextPage() {
    getDao().getList(getQueryBuilder().build()).apply {
        currentCount += size
        onListSuccess?.let { it(ArrayList(this)) }
    }
}
```

Reading about Reactive Programming gave me the passion to switch to a cleaner architecture, and since most of the companies require some knowledge about `RxJava`, why not ?

Most of the articles I found cover the basic concepts of using `RxJava` with room for getting a single item, or the whole list of data, but no one acctually extended to a more complex `Query`

Here's my expected `Dao`

```
@Dao
interface ListItemDao {

@Query("SELECT * FROM list ORDER BY lastModified DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset")
fun getPage(limit : Int, offset : Int) : Flowable<List<ListItem>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM list WHERE id = :itemId")
fun getItem(itemId : Int) : Flowable<ListItem>

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertItem(item : ListItem) : Completable

@Update
fun updateItem(item: ListItem) : Completable

@Delete
fun deleteItem(item : ListItem) : Completable
}
```

The question is, How to get `Paged` `Flowable` lists from a `Room` database while keeping the list reactive to additions and deletions? I think the old approach of using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` will not work here, neither the approach of getting the whole data from the database which consumes a lot of resources.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest to use the `Paging Library` when using `Room`. It's just two lines of code :)

Comment: Paging Library knows about the model, which would break the MVP architecture, wouldn't it?

Comment: Then you should ask yourself the question: Is MVP the right approach in this situation? It's fine to diverge a bit from given structures to simplify code. MVP is only a guideline which might not fit a 100% anytime. To go one step further: Why don't you want to use the adapter as a presenter?

Comment: @tynn I think the Adapter and ViewHolder are considered a part of the View layer, so using them as a presenter and passing the model between them would actually break stuff, wouldn't it ? I'm using interfaces to make things communicate together, the adapter should not know about the model, the presenter uses model's data to bind the ViewHolder through an interface, I have updated my code to make a better idea on how's the presenter binding the ViewHolder

Comment: @TamimAttafi I'm wondering if you've found any solution for this? I have the same problem!

Comment: @mohsen Unfortunately I haven't tried to find a solution. But as a workaround you can unsubscribe from your old data flow, clear data then load a new one with a larger limit but with 0 always offset. Then use DiffUtil to prevent updating the whole layout. This will get slower and slower to read from the database once you reach a large limit.

Comment: @mohsen You can also save your old data flow and merge it with the new one. Check merge method of flowable.

Comment: @mohsen Also you can use Sets instead of array lists to be able to merge lists without the risk of duplication